# How to setup Azure PAT token auto renewal?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I am using PAT token in Azure CLI to authenticate with azure pipeline and download the artifact. But PAT token maximum settable expiry is 1year. Is there any way to renew the expiry from the script(powershell or bash) non-interactive way? Can anyone provide a direction/example for the same?

I tried using service principal for the same. But it asks for a interactive login at least once which we are not expecting, as we are planning to give only the script for every users who need to download artifact.

Comment: I'd say that it is by design. Few years ago I was discussing this with MS representative and I was told, that the possibility to automatic / programatic regeneration is intentionally disabled.

Even regeneration is now disabled: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1181388/in-azure-devops-i-can-no-longer-extend-the-expirat?cid=kerryherger